# Can a downloaded zip file be opened, without saving it as a file first?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zip

I am downloading a zip file using the zend httpClient, and getting the contents of the file assigned to a variable as such:

```
$body = $response->getBody();
```

`$body` has the contents of a zip file, can it be opened **without saving** it as a file first, using http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php or some other 5.2 native class?

**EDIT** The suggestions gave some good ideas how it *may* be doable without making a temporary file, but due to the fact I'll need to be using the proxy adapter already, going to the lengths of creating an own adapter for the purpose of this, just isn't worth it.

I ended up using the tmpname to create a tmp file (which was something I wanted to avoid, but ended up here anyway).

```
   if ($response->isSuccessful()){
            $tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'Insight');
            if ($tmpfile!==false){                
                    $handle = fopen($tmpfile, "w");
                    if (fwrite($handle, $response->getBody())!==false){
                        $zip = new ZipArchive;
                        if ($zip->open($tmpfile) === TRUE) {
                            echo $zip->getFromIndex(0);
                            $zip->close();
                        } else {
                            $this->errorLog('Unable to open zip file '.$tmpfile);
                        } 

                    }else{
                        $this->errorLog('Unable to write to temporary file '.$tmpfile);
                    }
                    fclose($handle);                  
            }else{
                $this->errorLog('Unable to create temporary zip file in '.sys_get_temp_dir());
            }                          
        }else{
            $this->errorLog('Unable to download url '.$insightUrl);
        }
```

Comment: can't you just use `zip_open("http://url/to/download.zip")` ?

Comment: @Jules Need to use a proxy, and may have to use cookies as well. Not saying it perhaps couldn't be done with your way, but it most certainly would be easier if I could still use the zend http client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have very little knowledge of the Zend Framework, and absolutely nothing of Zend_Http_Client, but *maybe* you could use [compression stream wrappers](http://es.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) when initializing the `Zend_Http_Client` like this:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('zip://http://example.org/compressed_file.zip');
```

Comment: That does not unfortunately work. Message: Scheme "zip" is not supported

Comment: Message: Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

Comment: Well, it gets worse every time. Seems you can create a custom Zend_Http_Client_Adapter, assign it a new context created using stream_context_create and assign a filter compress.zip with stream_filter_append. Then assign this new adapter to the Zend_Http_Client. But I guess it's too much of a hassle, and also it may not work.

Comment: Creating a new adapter would probably work, but I will need to use the proxy adapter as well. Starting to extend on it and writing your own adapter, just for the sake of avoiding the creation of a temporary file perhaps just isn't worth the effort in this case. Thanks a lot for your input though, especially on those compression stream wrappers. First I've heard of them. I edited my question with the solution I ended up going with, similar to what Eugene suggested.

Comment: I'm happy that you learned something new :) although not useful in this situation :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP [Zip Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php).

Comment: `zip_open()` *only* takes a filename, not a string of data or some other resource.

Comment: Well tmpfile might and might not be considered as a stored file. If this is not an option to, then I don't see any other way at the moment.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use tmpfile() either, as it returns a resource, not a file? If in fact a temporary file will need to be created, it would have to be using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php ?